# Sysinternals Process Monitor device driver: procedure could not be found

Tags: windows-7, sysinternals, procmon

The most recent article I have found on this site regarding Systinternals Process Monitor is 13 years old. I must have missed something because I'm still having the same problem.

I have Windows 7 on this PC. (Haven't tried it yet on my Windows 11 PC.) I have procmon released September 29, 2023 and that seems to be the most recent. When I try to run it, it puts up the basic process window, albeit empty. The I get a box with the message:

> Unable to load process Monitor Device Driver: The specified procedure could not be found.

Since people experienced this (or *very* similar) problem 13 years ago I doubt that reverting to an older version (even if I could even find it) would be a solution.

I am sure this has been solved somewhere. Am I right?

Comment: ( https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sysinternals/issues/552 ) bug report thread states that "a permissions elevated CMD is not enough for the inital run. The first time launch requires true Admin permissions. Login as Admin." Try that?

Comment: Your problem is essentially your running Windows 7 and the application doesn’t support Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Your version of Process Monitor is new, and your Windows version
is too old. The two versions are not compatible.

The [latest  v3.96](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)
says:

> **Runs on**:
>
> Client: Windows 10 and higher.
> Server: Windows Server 2012 and higher.

It's
[said](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/760616/process-monitor-on-windows-7-sysinternals-system-r)
that Process Monitor v3.84 is the last version that supports
Vista and 7.

Here's the link to v3.84:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210820090300/https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessMonitor.zip

Comment: And there is nothing wrong with 3.84.  This app has changed very little since Mr. Russinovich wrote it.